# How to use CellTable<T> when T is an interface

Tags: gwt

in my current project I have to render items in a CellTable received via a RPC call. The columns must be created dynamically and the column types are unknown at compile time.

From the server side, I send a list of the following class to define a row in the table:

```
public class TableRowDTO implements IsSerializable {
  private List<IsTableItemDTO> tableItemDTOs;

  public TableRowDTO() {
    tableItemDTOs = new ArrayList<IsTableItemDTO>();
  }

  // getters & setters ...

}
```

Where each row will contain an item implementing IsTableItemDTO which is a marker interface:

```
public interface IsTableItemDTO extends IsSerializable {}
```

Implementing classes depict the actual controls/information to be shown in cells like:

```
public class TableDateTimeDTO extends IsTableItemDTO {
  private Date valueDate;
  // ... other fields not necessary for the table
}
```

Or also:

```
public class TableCheckBoxDTO extends AbstractTableItemDTO {
  private boolean checked;
  // ... other fields not necessary for the table
}
```

And also:

```
TablePasswordDTO extends AbstractTableItemDTO {
  private String valueText;
  // ... other fields not necessary for the table
}
```

Therefore, what I want to do for example in the case I receive a List with `{TableCheckBoxDTO, TableDateTimeDTO, TablePasswordDTO}` is to render a CellTable with the corresponding widgets.

I've seen [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/xOmuLuEuSes%20this), but I don't see how to apply any of the examples to my case especially because I cannot use thigs like **Column** as I don't have my **ContactInfo** before hand.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried directly using the interface? did you face any problem?

Comment: Hi @Onkar, what defines a row is `TableRowDTO` which contains `private List<IsTableItemDTO> tableItemDTOs;`. Do you mean something like: `Column<TableRowDTO, IsTableItemDTO> firstNameColumn`?

Comment: yes something similar...Also Define CellTable with the interface IsTableItemDTO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the marker interface `IsTableItemDTO` together with `instanceof()` and dynamic casts to have a generic `Column`/`Cell`.
There are 2 ways:

1. Create a [Composite Cell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html) and add all possible cell types and then display based on what specific sub-type your `isTableItemDTO` is.
2. Create a [custom cell](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html) and render the input (checkbox, text) based on the specific type of your marker interface

Answer (score 0):

I used Jet table (https://code.google.com/p/gwt-jet/) in one of my earlier projects. I believe it has the features you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is I don't have anything of the type `MyBean` as in  `JetTable<MyBean> jetTable = new JetSingleTable<MyBean>();` In my case, I have a List of objects implementing `IsTableItemDTO` and I must define for each implementation like `TableDateTimeDTO` which field to retrieve and show